# laravel one to many relationship column not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following models:

```
class Question extends Eloquent 
{
   public  function quiz()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('Quiz','id_quiz','id');
   }
   public  function answer()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('Answer');
   }
}

class Answer extends Eloquent
{
   public function question()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo('Question','id_question','id');
   }
}
```

In the controller I use:

```
$questions =  Question::with('answer')->whereHas(
     'quiz',  function($q) use($id) {$q->where('id', $id);
})->get();
```

I get the following error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'answers.question_id' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `answers` where `answers`.`question_id` in
>   (10, 11, 12, 13)))

Comment: The error already tells you your problem, read it.

Comment: Yes but i'dont have any column name question_id, i have id_question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should define your `answer` relationship in your `Question` model this way:

```
public  function answer(){
    return $this->hasMany('Answer','id_question','id');
}
```

because as you said you have column `id_question` and not `question_id` what is default value in this case.